# Explanation for what is happening in this certain for loop and if statement

Tags: javascript

What is happening in this `for` loop?

```
for (var i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
```

Can some please explain exactly what is happening in this part — `str[len - 1 - i]` — of the `if` statement?

```
if (str[i] !== str[len - 1 - i]) { 
  return false;
```

Comment: your pasted code needs some fixing. it's totally unclear what it looks like. Also, you tagged this as palindrome - you might want to mention why in your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's comparing the first character with the last, then the 2nd with the last but one, up to the centre of the string and returning false if there's a difference, i.e. if it's **not** a palindrome.